# How to hide style attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to hide style attribute in **html** so it still works? I mean this:

```
<html style="--color:#1E90FF;">
```

When I remove an attribut via **removeAttr**, it does not work at all. I can not do this via **CSS** this way:

```
:root {
   --color: dodgerblue;
}
```

since the value is inserted through **localStorage** based on value. Is there any way to paste it into **:root** with **jquery** without creating this **style** attribute? Any ideas?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheCzechTayen/7tLn094k/4/)**

Comment: The 'html' tag is also an element (basicallly the document), so adding to that will have impact.

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to avoid the `style` tag?

Comment: The reason is only a clearer HTML code. This technique can also be used for other projects

Answer (score 2):

If you have a "style" tag into your page, you can insert a CSS rule in it with "insertRule":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

```
document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].sheet.insertRule(":root { --color: dodgerblue; }");
```

You can also create a tag in which you insert the rule:

```js
document.getElementById('trigger').addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (!document.getElementById('myCustomStyle')) {

    var styleTag = document.createElement('style');
    styleTag.id = 'myCustomStyle';
    document.head.appendChild(styleTag);
    styleTag.sheet.insertRule(":root { --color: dodgerblue; }");
    styleTag.sheet.insertRule("p { color: var(--color); }");

  }

});
```

```html
<p>Click the button to insert CSS rules.</p>
<button id="trigger">INSERT</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your solution just creates a <style></style> in <head>. the number of times I click, it is repeatedly created

Comment: Don't insert it on a click event; insert it on page load.

Comment: Just set an "id" attribute on the tag and control if the tag exists with "getElementById". Answer edited.

Comment: NB: inserted rules are not viewable in devtools (Chrome at least) but are properly set.

Comment: I'm trying but it still does not work. Could you please update JSFiddle for me?